Add rows to grouped data frame so that set of levels of variable is complete
I need to add rows in a grouped data frame so that each group of Sequ has the same number of rows - 3 in this case - and to insert in variable X the missing levels of X, either A, B, or C :
df <- data.frame(
  Sequ = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  X = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B")
)

The desired output is this:
  Sequ X
1    1 A
2    1 B
3    1 C   # <-- row added
4    2 B
5    2 C
6    2 A   # <-- row added   
7    3 A
8    3 C
9    3 B


tidyr::complete(df, Sequ, X)? You have to ungroup first though, or make X a factor first.

Thanks that helps. Want to post as an answer?

I've linked to a duplicate instead :)
